# how does monodevelop version control work?

Tags: git, mono

I read [v2.6 supports GIT](http://monodevelop.com/Download/What%27s_new_in_MonoDevelop_2.6) with monodevelop's version control features, but I can't find anything having to do with version control in my install of monodevelop (stable 2.6).

I've tried right-clicking items, looked at all the menu options, etc.  In fact, I can't a single reference to anything having to do with version control in general must less git specifically.

I've got to be missing something 'cause the documentation makes it sound obvious.

Answer (score 25):

If version control is missing from your MonoDevelop installation and you're running Linux, try installing the [monodevelop-versioncontrol](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/monodevelop-versioncontrol) package. The documentation doesn't make this clear.

Comment: sudo apt-get install monodevelop-versioncontrol

Answer (score 11):

This is what can be done with project which is already in svn or git version control (in my  MonoDevelop):
[image: Screenshot of MonoDevelop]

Apart from the menu options you can see the bar at the bottom of the editor in which options like blame or log are available.

If your project is not under source control yet, the option to publish it will be available. You should be also able to checkout repository from the main MonoDevelop window.

This is all from MonoDevelop 3.1, so maybe some of these options were introduced later? True or not, I recommend you using the newest version anyway, the code completions is **much** better and SCM operations are faster. Not mentioning a lot of other minor fixes.

Comment: It should be mentioned that Push and commit work, and also Review changes. However, Update/Pull doesn't really work. I usually just reset from github via command-line: git fetch --all; git reset --hard origin/master