# In MonoDevelop, what causes the “red-x” error-icon when my solution builds and runs without errors?

Tags: monodevelop

I've created a small Hello World ASP.NET project in MonoDevelop. Those red-x (red diagonal crosses) appeared on most of the file icons in my solution, at the bottom right.

The project still compiles and runs, and there are no obvious problems or indication what causes them. I tried hovering the cursor over the icons but no tooltip appears.

Do these icons indicate a real problem with my project, or do they just appear at random?

Here's a screenshot of the problem solution (left), and a fresh solution for comparison (right):

[image][image]

Comment: Does anything show up in the "Error List"?

Comment: Hm, there is no  "Error List" pane currently visible anywhere, only Source, Changes, Blame, Log, Merge. How do I activate it? Edit: Is it this - http://i.stack.imgur.com/tl5Xq.png?

Comment: I think it's under View > Error List.

Comment: There is no View->Error List. My version 4.0.12, I'm on Ubuntu and installed it from the repos, so it may be slightly older.

Comment: The image you linked to was the pane I was thinking of... are you building in MonoDevelop?

Comment: Yes, from Build->Rebuild All. Do you mean as opposed to building from the command line?

Comment: There should be a "Build project in MonoDevelop" checkbox under `Tools > Preferences > Unity > Debugger`

Comment: Is there repository control on it, like `git` or `svn`? Red crosses might indicate non-pushed changes or something.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt There is, I manually created a local git repo, using `git init` from the command line. I do have uncommitted changes. There is no remote repo setup so nothing has been pushed. Edit: I tried commiting everything, but the red crosses still remain. Edit 2: I also created a remote repo, and pushed the changes, but the red icons remain.

Comment: Are the files atleast added? Sounds like it's complaining about non-indexed files, `git add *` might help. Or try randomly pushing buttons in that context menu (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10829807/5296568). But pretty sure the "error" lies within the version control.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Thanks, I tried that. I staged, committed and pushed the changes, but the icons still remain, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red error overlay icon is from version control.

If you are using Git then red icon means the file has been deleted and recreated when compared with the last commit.

One way to reproduce this is to create a new C# console project with a local git repository. Commit the new project to Git locally, no need to push it to a remote repository. Then with MonoDevelop delete Program.cs and then create a new Program.cs file again in the same location. Then you should see a red icon which means the file is marked as removed in Git.

If you then open up a command line and run `git status` you should see something like:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    MyProject/Program.cs

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   MyProject/MyProject.csproj

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    MyProject/Program.cs
```

Comment: Thanks. I suspected it was that, because the red X-es disappeared on their own after I did a stash/stash pop and some other git actions, although I'm not sure what the exact sequence was.